# Specific React code not rendered in IE11

Tags: reactjs

I've written a small component that renders correctly in Chrome and Firefox, but not IE11. The main entry point to the application has got IE compatibility set:

```
doctype html
html
  head
  meta(http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible', content='IE=edge')
  title= title
  link(rel='stylesheet', href='./stylesheets/eventinfo.css')
body
block content
```

My compoment looks like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import { SettingsPane, SettingsPage, SettingsContent, SettingsMenu} from 'react-settings-pane';
import {Col, Form, FormGroup, FormControl, ControlLabel, HelpBlock, Button, Alert, Checkbox} from 'react-bootstrap'
import { Creatable } from 'react-select';

const Settings = React.createClass({

    render: function () {
        var data = this.props.data;
        var envFilter = data["settings.notifications.environments"] || "";
        var isChecked = this.props.data['settings.notifications.receiveMailNotifications'];

        const menu = [
            {
                title: 'Email warnings',
                url: '/settings/notifications'
            }
        ];

        // Save settings after close
        let leavePaneHandler = (wasSaved, newSettings, oldSettings) => {
            // "wasSaved" indicates wheather the pane was just closed or the save button was clicked.

            if (wasSaved) {
                var environmentsObject = newSettings["settings.notifications.environments"];
                var environments = environmentsObject.toString();
                var applications = newSettings["settings.notifications.applications"];

                this.props.onSubmit(newSettings);

            }
        };

        return (
            <SettingsPane items={menu} index="/settings/notifications" settings={data}
                          onChange={this.settingsChanged} onPaneLeave={leavePaneHandler}>
                <SettingsMenu headline="Settings"/>
                <SettingsContent header={true}>
                    <SettingsPage handler="/settings/notifications">
                        <FormGroup>
                            <Col componentClass={ControlLabel} sm={2} />
                            <Col sm={10}>
                                <label>
                                <input
                                    type="checkbox"
                                    checked={isChecked}
                                    onChange={this.props.toggleMailNotification}
                                    />
                                    Receive mail notification for these environments
                                    </label>
                            </Col>
                        </FormGroup>
                        <FormGroup>
                            <Col componentClass={ControlLabel} sm={2}>
                                <div>
                                    <label>Miljø/miljøklasse</label>
                                </div>
                            </Col>
                            <Col sm={10} className="dummy">
                                <Creatable
                                    name="settings.notifications.environments"
                                    options={this.props.options}
                                    value={envFilter}
                                    onChange={this.props.handleEnvironmentsChange}
                                    multi={true}
                                    allowCreate={true}
                                    tabSelectsValue={false}
                                    className="settings-creatable"
                                    placeholder="Enter environments"
                                />
                            </Col>
                        </FormGroup>
                    </SettingsPage>
                </SettingsContent>
            </SettingsPane>
        )
    }
});


export default Settings;
```

How should I go about identifying exactly what causes IE11 not to render this code? There's no error in the console. Any advice will be appreciated.

Comment: Do you use babel or something?

Comment: That is not "a small component." Anyway, do other components render correctly? What if you replace this with `const Settings = () => <div>Hello</div>;` or what if you replace your `render` function with `function () { return <div>Hello</div>; }`? The first step to fixing a bug like this is figuring out what *does* work.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answers. I ended up rewriting the code based on react-bootstrap components, instead of debugging this one. 
Next time I'll use the debugging suggestions provided in the comments section.